# What Supply Shack items are unique to the store?

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

There are a few items I'd buy at the Supply Shack in-game store but I'm afraid that they're otherwise hidden throughout the game. What Supply Shack items can be found in other parts of the game, and what happens if I purchase the item before I find it? Would I find the money in the chest instead or is the money wasted?

In the case of the Crafting/Enhancement/Refinement Tools, of which I know some are found hidden in the world, what happens if I purchase the item before finding it in a chest? Do I automatically unlock the next highest level of tool, or would I pay full price each time for each tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the crafting and enhancement tools can be found in a strongbox at various points in the game. The REFINEMENT tool (level 4 crafting) *must* be purchased. 175 coins. So save up for that at a minimum.

I do not know if buying one at the store upgrades you if you find a strongbox with the equivalent after purchase.

Answer (score 1):

I can verify, because it just occurred in my game, that if you purchase a lower level tool from the shack, you will receive the next higher tool out in the wild. I accidentally bought the enhancement tool from the shack and just now found the refinement tool where I believe I was meant to find the enhancement tool.  This does suggest that you must purchase at least one tool from the shack, but it doesn't need to be the refinement tool.

Answer (score 0):

they cant be found in the world itself. they are exclusive to this ingame shop.

Comment: I found Crafting & Enhancement in chests, so I'm not sure where you're getting that info

Comment: its not the same. there are 3 diffrent crafting and enhancement tools. one for each level

Level 1 is automatically unlocked and then you can find 3 more. Two in the world and the last one is buyable in the shack

It doesnt matter which one is obtained first.